# Please explain this code is for Articles.events.publish

Tags: mean.io

I'm looking for help to understand this code from the sample module Articles in the mean.io generated app. I can't figure out what Articles.events.publish is for.

file: packages/core/articles/server/controllers/articles.js

```
     create: function(req, res) {
        var article = new Article(req.body);
        article.user = req.user;

        article.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: 'Cannot save the article'
                });
            }

            Articles.events.publish({
                action: 'created',
                user: {
                    name: req.user.name
                },
                url: config.hostname + '/articles/' + article._id,
                name: article.title
            });

            res.json(article);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's used to send data to stacksight. For detail, you can refer Module's constructor in node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/module/index.js, and you can find stacksight under node_modules/meanio/node_modules/stacksight.

But it will NOT send these information by default, it needs to request app id and API token from [stacksight](https://apps.stacksight.io/) first.